# Winter Bash 2016 Loungin Around conditions

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

Looking at the conditions for the [Loungin Around hat](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/loungin-around)

[image]

Does the condition become invalidated if you subsequently edit the question on a computer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No since to get the hat, you need to post it first on the Android or iOS app and get the "Nice Question" badge (score of 10 or higher). It can only be invalidated if you originally posted it on the computer. Remember that posting the question and editing the question are two different things.